# Regexp to extract inner content of a html tag

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex that extracts the content of a html tag. In this case, I need to extract and parse the content of a div element. The HTML code inside the div element can be anything and I need to extract all.

I'm using the next regexp, but doesn't work in all cases.

```
<div\s+id="body"[^>]*>(?<PARAM1>(?:(?:(?!<div[^>]*>|</div>).)+|<div[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</div>)*)</div>
```

It doesn't works because extracted group PARAM1, stops in a closing div tag element before the desired one, and I can't found why.

The HTML looks like this:

```
(...any HTML...)<div id="body">
<div class="container">

    <ul class="breadcrumb">...SOME <li><p>....
    </ul>   

    <h1>...</h1>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>...</dt>
                <dd>..</dd>
                <dt>..</dt>
                <dd>..</dd>             
            </dl>
                <hr/>   
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>..</dt>
                <dd>..</dd>             
            </dl>       

        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <p class="text-center">
                <img ...>                       
            </p>
        </div> **(STOPS HERE)**
    </div>

       <div> .... ANY HTML </div>

</div> (...more HTML...)
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I will be first one to do this, do NOT use regex for HTML parsing. Check this out: [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: Let me add that it is impossible to do that with regex because of different grammar complexity classes.

Comment: Don't use Regex for this, HTMLAgilityPack is about 29 times more suited.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/642532

It is impossible. Use an XML parser instead.

Comment: I'm now sure that it's not the best option. I was already evaluating the HTMLAgilityPack as alternative. Thanks a lot